# Настройка БД mysql на Windows Server 2022

Tags: mysql, windows-server

Мне нужно организовать бд для своей игры на unity. Но мне нужен доступ к нему 24/7 и из любой сессии. И я решил установить на свой пк windows server 2022 и mysql и организовать сервер с бд на этом пк. Но я не знаю с чего начать.

Comment: Windows server  дорогая вещь, сначала собрать финансовые средства, или использовать временно на тестовый период в познавательных целях.

Comment: этот проект как раз и для познавательных целей так что я взял его на тестовый период

Comment: Windows server не обязательное условие, можно использовать и не серверную ОС в тестовых целях. А вообще  установить ОС, установить MySQL и можно пользоваться базой данных. Какие возникают проблемы?

Comment: Хорошо, тогда как мне организовать удалённое подключение к бд? По задумке при входе в игру, я вхожу или регистрируюсь и мне нужно что бы это можно было сделать с любого устройства. Значит мне нужен будет доступ к ней постоянно поэтому я выбрал серверное ос

Comment: Примерно так :     `https://habr.com/ru/articles/495698/`

Comment: Хорошо. Моя игра - клиент сервером в данном случае по сути выступает любой клиент так как пользователь при входе может создать свою карту. Но я хочу организовать обмен данными между всеми пользователями, ну то есть по сути каждая карта это отдельная таблица в бд с данными игроков